# Does Eigen optimize matrix operations involving multiplications with hard-coded 0 elements?

Tags: eigen, eigen3

I know that Eigen actually creates the final matrix (to the left, in assignment) after the entire matrix equation (on the right) has been condensed into a single matrix operation. I also know that there are compilation flags that enable using Eigen with optimized instructions (which are often cpu vendor and architecture dependent). I would like to know if Eigen is able to

1. Detect when a 0 (zero) is a hard-coded element in a matrix
2. Use that knowledge to optimize a matrix operation so that it assigns that element directly to 0 in the final matrix assignment
3. Do this optimization with several operations in the matrix equation (such as multiple additions and multiplications and parenthesis)

In a dream world, the computer would recognize when those extra FPU operations are not necessary.

Can Eigen do this optimization?
How difficult would it be to program in this optimization if it is currently not implemented?
I am using Dense matrices.

Comment: Please be more specific! Are you talking about sparse matrices? Or having a few zeroes in part of an expression? How do you "hard-code" the zero elements? What expressions are you talking about?

Comment: I am not super familiar with sparse matrices...
The matrices are of type Eigen:Matrix<double, 3, 3>
Does that answer your question?
I am not including anything with the word "sparse" in it.

Comment: It looks like it is a Dense matrix, not a sparse matrix. Does it matter what type? If the optimization was there, why would it matter what type of matrix it was? The multiplication with "0" produces "0" whether we are talking about ints, doubles, equations, expressions, or any other numerical object. I don't know why the matrix type matters.

Comment: `0.0*(-1.0)` is `-0.0` and `0.0 * infinity` is `NaN`, so you can't just optimize that away. That said, small dense matrix expressions are typically completely unrolled at compile time by Eigen, so if your compiler agrees that certain values are known, it may be able to optimize some calculations away: https://godbolt.org/z/CMNTrH (notice the difference `-ffast-math` makes).